# crtdbg dumps a memory leak when sf::Text::setOutlineThickness is used

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sfml

Working with SFML 2.4.2 on Windows 7 64-bit version, I've noticed an issue with `sf::Text::setOutlineThickness(float)`. Once it is used in the program, except for default value 0, crtdbg dumps a memory leak of various sizes of bytes but always the same amount. I believe this is related to the size of the string, if the text gets drawn, and [if the parameter of `setOutlineThickness` is accepted](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Text.cpp#L201), demonstrated here:

```
/// Initial set-up
sf::Text test;
test.setString("A");
// ... Set charactersize, font, fillcolor, etc ...
test.setOutlineThickness(1);
test.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);

/// Make a drawcall for test later in the program
void Game::draw(sf::RenderTarget & target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    target.draw(test, states);
}
```

This produces a leak:

```
{8601} normal block at 0x0000000005CA5C90, 60 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 03 00 07 00 0B 00 0F 00 13 00 17 00 1B 00 1F 00
{8600} normal block at 0x0000000005E03A20, 120 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
{8599} normal block at 0x0000000005E2A680, 960 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 0D 01 00 00 80 07 00 00
{8598} normal block at 0x0000000005CA36B0, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <        h       > F0 1A 9D 05 00 00 00 00 68 AE 83 DB FE 07 00 00
```

If `test.setString("B");`, there are still four blocks but the byte size differs, since the string uses another character:
68 bytes, 136 bytes, 1088 bytes, 72 bytes.
Finally if `test.setString("AB");`, there are 8 blocks with the expected sizes:

```
{8667} normal block at 0x0000000005C35D10, 68 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 03 00 07 00 0B 00 0F 00 13 00 17 00 1B 00 1F 00
{8666} normal block at 0x0000000005C61310, 136 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
{8665} normal block at 0x000000000325CDE0, 1088 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 0D 01 00 00 80 07 00 00
{8664} normal block at 0x0000000005C340D0, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <        h       > F0 1A 96 05 00 00 00 00 68 AE B5 DB FE 07 00 00
{8601} normal block at 0x0000000005C35C90, 60 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 03 00 07 00 0B 00 0F 00 13 00 17 00 1B 00 1F 00
{8600} normal block at 0x0000000005D93A20, 120 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
{8599} normal block at 0x0000000005DBA680, 960 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 80 07 00 00 0D 01 00 00 80 07 00 00
{8598} normal block at 0x0000000005C336B0, 72 bytes long.
 Data: <        h       > F0 1A 96 05 00 00 00 00 68 AE B5 DB FE 07 00 00
```

- I use sf::Text as a private member of a class which should be destroyed with the class but that doesn't seem to be the case. What am I missing?
- I use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);`, is this a false positive?
- Glancing at the function, [sf::Text::setOutlineThickness](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Text.cpp#L180-L206), I don't see an issue here. [A brief documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Text.php#ab0e6be3b40124557bf53737fe6a6ce77).
- Different leaks depending on the size of the string is more of a symptom really, it's the drawcall and non-default value on outline thickness that I'm clueless on.

Comment: `sf::Text::draw()` has some slightly different behavior when the outline thickness is non-zero: `if (m_outlineThickness != 0)  target.draw(m_outlineVertices, states);`.  Also, `sf::Text::ensureGeometryUpdate()` has some code that's conditional on outline thickness non-zero. I'd look at those areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a real leak in SFML, at [Font.cpp#L561](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/c43b5991afe815ef92a812d67f8af12b0143adfd/src/SFML/Graphics/Font.cpp#L561)

It looks like this:

```
FT_Glyph_Stroke(&glyphDesc, stroker, false);
```

But according to the docu of [FT_Glyph_Stroke](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_stroker.html#FT_Glyph_Stroke), it should actually be this, so the source glyph is destroyed:

```
FT_Glyph_Stroke(&glyphDesc, stroker, true);
```

Comment: Looks like you're right! Working on new binaries for SFML with that line modified to true. The ones I've tested indicates that there are no longer any memory leaks. I'll mark this as answered as soon as the SFML-team has confirmed it. What prompted you to look at Font.cpp?

Comment: @Chringo, I used my own memory leak detection tool [heob](https://github.com/ssbssa/heob), it showed that the `glyphDesc` in the call from `FT_Get_Glyph()` was never freed. The rest I figured out with debugging.